# given f and the function composition fog, find g

Tags: matrices, function-and-relation-composition

someone just gave me a question to solve and i've been wondering how to solve it:
given f\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4\\2&3&4&1\end{bmatrix}
and fog\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4\\3&1&4&2\end{bmatrix}
find g=?
i'd appreciate your help. I can find it by guessing but i'm looking for the exact solution. Thanks

Comment: $3=f\circ g(1)=f(g(1))$. But $f(2)=3$ so what is $g(1)$?

Comment: i'm missing something here. How do we refer to this function's members? it should have rows and columns right? so how can we say,for example, g(1). if g(1)=2, which member(row and column) does it exactly refer to?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Sina, what is the secret code of that set of patterns? I see matrices, not functions so far...

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably not going to go through every element, but let's consider the mapping of 1. We know that $f^{-1}(3) = 2$ and the $(f(g(1)) = 3$. So it seems that we'll need $g(1)$ to be 2, as we will then have $f(g(1)) = f(2) = 3$.

You can follow this line of reasoning to find the rest of g in the exact same way

Answer (score 0):

let F: y -> z and G x -> y
FoG(x)=z,let invF be the inverse function of F.

`invFoFoG=(invFoF)oG=G`.

**G=invF(z)**

invF is the following mapping which the same as G:

1 -> 4

2 -> 1

3 -> 2

4 -> 3